# How to set text on the secondary tile in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I want to show a text across the middle of the secondary live tile (not the small text at the bottom). I am struggling to find any documenttion of how to do it. I know it was possible in WP 8, but I wonder if this functionality is still available?! I also want to it from code not from XAML.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the tile template catalog for Windows Runtime apps?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx

Comment: Yes, but I wonder if there is a way to set the text before you have sent the notification.